# how to change baseUrl path in init.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I need to define a nodejs library (from `pr_name/node_modules/lib_name`). At my `pr_name/static/js/init.js` file I defined a `baseUrl` path:

```
baseUrl: 'static',
```

then I defined some `paths` at static dir. How can I add the node library from different path?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'static',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'jquery.maskedinput': 'libs/jquery.maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min',
        'bootstrap': 'libs/bootswatch-dist/js/bootstrap.min',
        'xlsx-chart': '???' // <-- not at static but at node_modules
    }
```

**Upd.**

```
'xlsx-chart': '/node_modules/xlsx-chart/chart',
```

and

```
'xlsx-chart': '../node_modules/xlsx-chart/chart',
```

both gives me an error at browser console.

```
require.js:165 Uncaught Error: Script error for "xlsx-chart", needed by: export-stats
```

where export-stats has an xlsx-chart require:

```
define(['xlsx-chart'], function(XLSXChart){ 
....
```

I can't understand the source of problem.

**Upd.Upd.**
Now I understand - my site is `python`'s and all of used urls must be defined at `urls.py`. And `'xlsx-chart'` goes to its own url like same `node.js`-library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the server that serves your data is configured, you could use an absolute path:

```
'xlsx-chart': '/node_modules/xlsx-chart'
```

If `node_modules` is not at the root of what the server serves, a relative path can also work and perhaps be nicer in some cases:

```
'xlsx-chart': '../node_modules/xlsx-chart'
```

I've used both.

Comment: I get a strange error at browser console. I already updated a question.